# SearchRecentSuggestions.clearHistory() not working

Tags: android, autocomplete

I am implementing an Activity with a search bar with autocomplete suggestions which is working fine.

In the settings screen I have an option to "Clear search history" and when the user clicks it, the toast appears indicating everything went well but the search suggestions keep appearing when I search again.

```
layoutClearHistory.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SearchRecentSuggestions suggestions = new SearchRecentSuggestions(SettingsActivity.this,
                        MySuggestionProvider.AUTHORITY, MySuggestionProvider.MODE);
                suggestions.clearHistory();

                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, R.string.search_history_cleared, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

I followed [the official android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html) but the autocomplete history keeps appearing.

Any ideas where i could be messing it up? thanks!

Comment: are you sure that you're cleaning right suggestions? I mean got them in same way as you using?

Comment: It's the only one i got :S thanks!